# how to assign javascript value to jsp variable in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a text field, I need to send these text value to the same page which is in jsp .

I just want to assign javascript value to jsp variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. JSP runs on the server, Javascript runs on the client, so when Javascript runs the JSP variable doesnt exist anymore.

Consider using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 2):

You could set a hidden field.

Put this in your JSP form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="foo" name="foo" />
```

Execute this script whenever you want to fill the field:

```
document.getElementById("foo").value = "some value";
```

When you submit the form, it'll be available as follows in the servlet:

```
String foo = request.getParameter("foo"); // "some value"
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Communication between Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)

Comment: request.getParameter() takes a form element and moreover it refreshes the page, is there any other method to achieve this? If i dont wanna use ajax...